# How do I generate a random variable between 4 variables?

Tags: java, random

For example, I have a,b,c,d, which are int variables and I need to know the way to generate one random variable. Thats a part of my code:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = m.getlength()-2;
int d = m.getlength()-1;
int r = rand.nextInt();//I think I have to use this but I dont know how.
```

Comment: What you mean with "generate one random variable."?

Comment: Well, think about how many options there are. Then work out how to get an integer that could take one of that many values... and then make each value correspond to one of your variables...

Comment: `nextInt(x)` produces an integer between 0 and x-1.

Comment: @MarcoAcierno I want to randomly take one of those variables(a,b,c,d)

Comment: Well, you could say: if it's 0: a, 1: b, 2: c, 3: d...

Comment: Finally,it was easy... I want to thank you all for your answers.Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Define a method

```
private static final Random random = new Random();
private static int pickRandom(int ... a)
{
    return a[random.nextInt(a.length)];
}
```

Then you can call

```
int r = pickRandom(a,b,c,d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would use rand.nextInt() to generate a random number.  If you want the integer to be, say between 0 and up to 80, you would use

```
int r = rand.nextInt(80);
```

and you may get back 0-79.

Does this answer your question?  You can also take a look at the documentation: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28int%29)